# Enable Enhanced protected mode in IE programmatically

Tags: c#, internet-explorer-11, windows-7-x64

Is there any way we can enable EPM in IE 11 using C# or any other way? Does IE allow to change security parameter to change externally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is **NO**. You cannot change the enhanced protected mode programatically. Also refer: 
[HowTo: Deal with Protected Mode API in Internet Explorer 7 and IE8](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2009/06/12/internet-explorer-protected-mode-api/)